# Missing required parameter for [Route: signup] [URI: signup/{code}] [Missing parameter: code]

Tags: php, laravel-8

im making a webpage with laravel and this issue appeared.
I used some routes with get to pass parameters via ID, using `::find` in the controllers. But after creating a new function to signup via code, server says that im not passing correctly the parameter code, can anybody help me?

Function

```
public function signup($code){
        $user=User::where('confirmation_code',"=",$code)->first();
        if($user!=null){
            return view('signup',compact('user'));
        }
        else{
            return view('inicio');
        }
    }
```

Route

```
Route::get('/signup/{code}', 'App\Http\Controllers\PagesController@signup')->name('signup');
```

And finally the call

```
<a  href="{{route('signup',['code' =>$user->confirmation_code])}}" class="uppercase font-extrabold py-4 px-8 rounded-3xl"> signup</a>
```

I already tried making a DD in the signup function and the code is shown correctly, so i cant find the issue here, options?

Answer (score 0):

If you're under Laravel version 8, change the route sintax to:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\PagesController;

Route::get('/signup/{code}', [PagesController::class,'signup'])->name('signup');
```

Also be sure that value of confirmation_code isn't null.

Comment: Im using laravel 8 so that isnt the issue, i already have the `if` to check if the code is null, because doesnt find any user in the `::were` clause. I also tried doing a dd and the code shows properly. When the confirmation_code is null the function redirects to the view 'inicio'.
Thanks for the answer.